# Trying to Update Multipe Items in SubRow - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Context : There is Parent Row with Name and Amount, and Sub rows are children and division of parent with Name and Amount

The Problem : I want to Update Multiple Sub Rows and Calculate the Amount for Each Row
Example : Parent has Amount of 5000, Childrens
Jan - 2000
Feb - 1000
Other 3 should have 666.66 Automatically

What I have tried
I can edit single amount now rest updates automatically
Example
Jan - 2000
Other four to 750 each automatically

Code:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  const [previousSubAmount, setPreviousSubAmount] = useState(0);
  const [data, setData] = useState([
    {
      name: 'Admission Fee',
      amount: 5000,
      months: [
        { name: 'Jan', amount: 1000 },
        { name: 'Feb', amount: 1000 },
        { name: 'Mar', amount: 1000 },
        { name: 'Apr', amount: 1000 },
        { name: 'May', amount: 1000 }
      ]
    }
  ]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setPreviousSubAmount(data[0].amount / data[0].months.length);
  }, [data]);

  const handleSubRowChange = (
    totalAmount: number,
    newSubAmount: any,
    monthName: string
  ) => {
    let row: any = data[0];
    let remainingAmount = Number(totalAmount) - Number(newSubAmount);
    let exactAmount = Number(remainingAmount) / Number(row.months.length - 1);
    let updatedMonths = row.months.map((month: any) => {
      if (monthName === month.name) {
        return {
          ...month,
          amount: newSubAmount,
        };
      } else {
        return {
          ...month,
          amount: exactAmount,
        };
      }
    });

    setPreviousSubAmount(newSubAmount);

    setData([{ ...row, months: updatedMonths }]);
  };

  return (
    <>
      {data?.map(e => {
        return <div>
          <div style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row' }}>
            <span>{e?.name}</span>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;
            <span>{e?.amount}</span>
          </div>
          <div>
            {
              e?.months.map(m => {
                return <div style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                  <span>{m?.name}</span>
                  &nbsp;&nbsp;
                  <input type='text' value={m.amount.toString()} onChange={(event) => {
                    handleSubRowChange(
                      e.amount,
                      event.target.value,
                      m.name
                    )
                  }}></input>
                </div>
              })
            }
          </div>
        </div>
      })}
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

What I have tried
I can edit single amount now rest updates automatically
Example
Jan - 2000
Other four to 750 each automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seemed like a simple question, but it is tricky problem and there are some case scenarios that need to be handled,

Here are some key points to consider.

1. Once we update any value we need to keep a flag for updated values and non-updated values

```
    {
      name: "Admission Fee",
      amount: 5000,
      months: [
        { name: "Jan", amount: 1000, isUpdated: false },
        { name: "Feb", amount: 1000, isUpdated: false },
        { name: "Mar", amount: 1000, isUpdated: false },
        { name: "Apr", amount: 1000, isUpdated: false },
        { name: "May", amount: 1000, isUpdated: false }
      ]
    }
  ]);
```

2. Whenever you will change the value of any input `isUpdated` flag will change to `true`
3. Once all values are edited, then you need to make sure the sum of all amounts is still equal to the total amount.
4. Also need to manage amount exceed case and less amount case.

I have added a code for your help, hope you will find the solution to your problem statement.

https://codesandbox.io/s/update-multipe-items-in-subrow-react-3f88ku?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Awesome, you are great 

Comment: @NawazPasha if it was helpful, could you please accept the answer and upvote. It did take efforts and time to consider all the case scenarios and provide solution for this questions

Comment: Thank you  for the answer. I really appreciate that you took the time to tackle such a tricky problem and even addressed several use cases that I had overlooked before. It is highly appreciated.